# Calling string from another file

Tags: java

So i got these strings i my main file named "Login" as is the class

```
public JPasswordField passfield;
public JTextField userfield;
public JTextField hostfield;
public String host;
public String user;
public String pwd;

JButton buttoncon = new JButton("Connect");
    //buttoncon.addActionListener(buttonconClick());

    buttoncon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonconClick();
        } 
        } );


public void buttonconClick() {  
    if(hostfield.getText().length()==0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tomt ip felt");
    else if(userfield.getText().length()==0)
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tomt brukernavn felt");
    else if(passfield.getPassword().length==0)
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tomt passord felt");
    else{
          host = hostfield.getText();
          host = "jdbc:mysql://" + host;
          user = userfield.getText();
          char[] pass = passfield.getPassword();
          pwd = String.copyValueOf(pass); 
        }
```

then the connection to DB

i need to call these strings in my second file i also have the file importet

```
import test.Login;

JButton Worldselect = new JButton("World");
    Worldselect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                Login mysqlcon = new Login();
                String hostcon = mysqlcon.host;
                hostcon = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostcon;
                String usercon = mysqlcon.user;
                String pwdcon = mysqlcon.pwd;

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(hostcon,usercon,pwdcon);
```

But when i do it like that they retun emty, why is that?

Comment: Please post the full code for `Login`, if it can easily fit in your question.

Comment: Your code example of `Login` as it stands does not compile. My guess is you left something out that is essential. Where are the values initialized?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Post something reproductible please, when are those fields are declared ? The fields are sets ? You should look to create a [mcve]

Comment: You don't ever call `buttonconClick`, so the strings are never assigned

Comment: Since you build an instance then try to get values without calling `buttonconCilck` and without settings the fields to this instance, the values will be null. You need to debug this to understand your problem

Comment: Finally I agree you are right @AxelH

Answer (score 0):

In short, you build an instance of `Login` that will look like this :

```
Login {
    passfield;
    userfield = null;
    hostfield = null;
    host = null;
    user = null;
    pwd = null;
}
```

And next, you tried to access those values. Off course they are null.

You need to call your method `buttonconClick` to set those values BUT you first need to set the three fields instance to prevent the `NullPointerException` that you will face. Once this is done, the instance will have the values you expect.

In your case, you should create the `Login` instance outside of the ActionListener, where the fields exists, set the fields into the instance. And only on click, you will check the fields values with the methods then, if this works (you should use a boolean), tried to connect.

EDIT :

Here is part of your code :

```
Login mysqlcon = new Login();
String hostcon = mysqlcon.host;
```

You are creating the instance `mysqlcon` but you used it directly. There is no constructor in your class so every field will be null,^.

Comment: I guess i understand what you mean by this, but how to implement it is another thing(not very familiar with coding at all) i guess i forgot to mention that there is two buttons, one in each file and i want it to get the info from the first button click. ill look some more.

Comment: @Leifus, In theory, Login should not work with the fields directly, you should give him the String, from the constructor and/or with setter. To the when, this is up to you. I can't really help you more.

Comment: You totally got it wrong, the OP ask to reuse the values stored in Login class in the DB class

Comment: @UmarAta, OP want to store the value of an screen into a Login class then use the instance to connect to a DB. But since he never assign any value to his Login instance, this will not work ... Yes he want to "reuse the values of Login" but first, he need to assign those...